# Ошибка при отправке сообщения с форматированием Markdown

Tags: python, telebot

Имеется переменная с форматированием:

```
info = f'''
Данные
├Имя: {first} {last}
├ID: `{userid}`
├Ник: @{nick}
└Номер телефона: `{phone}`
    '''
```

При попытке отправить через -
`bot.send_message(ID, info, parse_mode='Markdown')`

Получаю ошибку - `2021-12-22 22:58:37,365 (__init__.py:510 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse entities: Can't find end of the entity starting at byte offset 80"`

Проблема в передаваемой переменной `{nick}` прим. Ygfgh_Ygfgh, похоже что она содержит нижнее подчеркивание. Как возможно решить?

Comment: поменяй parse_mode на HTML, либо попробуй эранировать этот символ обратным слэшем

Comment: Спасибо, ваш комментарий помог мне разобраться!